# Select at least one record from each group mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have table of 10 million records and it will still grow and there are more 1000 thousand users who will be executing this query at the same time...

Here is how my table looks like :[image: Table Structure]

So I want when :

`select * from tbl_bol group by categorie order by categorie desc`

query is executed by those users the execution should not exceed 1 sec and at least from each categorie(from categorie column)  on record must be in the result.

The current problem I have is the query execution is taking long is bring only the top categorie(column) records .

How should I write the query to give that result I want and improve the performance? I have index on categorie.

Comment: I think when you get to a database of this size, you can afford to seek professional help.

Comment: What do you mean by professional help?

Comment: The kind you pay for.

Comment: So I will learn it from that professional help...terrible

Comment: OK, well maybe see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)